# Footer overlapping content (Couldn't find the solution with search engine..)

Tags: html, css, footer, overlapping, portfolio

So...I'm creating a new portfolio for myself and everything works perfectly fine..except for the footer.
I got 4 pages on my portfolio, 3 of them are short so the footer doesn't overlap, but on my "portfolio" page the footer overlaps the content because he has a fixed position.
Any ideas?

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="img/bg.jpg" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div class="box">
    <img src="images/Portfolio-tryout_01.png" />
    <div class="links">
        <div class="home">
            <a href="Index.html"><img src="images/house_home.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <a href="Portfolio.html"><img src="images/Portfolio.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <a href="Services.html"><img src="images/About.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <a href="Contact.html"><img src="images/contact.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="gallery">
        <h3 style="color: white; font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; font-size: 18px; margin-left: 25px;">Photomanipulations</h3>
        <div class="holder"><!--image 1-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/AThingCalledLove.jpg" title="title for lightbox goes here"><img src="images/thumbs/AThingCalledLove.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A Thing Called Love</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 2-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/model.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/model.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A Model with lighting effects</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 3-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/WomanBlindfolded.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/WomanBlindfolded.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Blindfolded Woman</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 4-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/crane-lge.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/crane_thumb.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A large crane at work on site</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->
        <div class="holder"><!--image 5-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/leaf-lge.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/leaf.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A leaf with water splashes</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 6-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/liberty-lge.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/liberty.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Statue of Liberty - New York</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 7-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/lioness-lge.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/lioness.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A yawning Lioness in Africa</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 8-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/owl-lge.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/owl.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>A midnight Owl landing on a perch</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <h3 style="color: white; font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; font-size: 18px; margin-left: 25px;">Sites Web </h3>
        <div class="holder"><!--image 9-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/Bibliojette.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/Bibliojette.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Bibliojette (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 10-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/cpbbw.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/cpbbw.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>CPBBW (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 11-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/Grunge Mania.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/GrungeMania.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Grunge (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 12-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/Minimalism.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/Minimalism.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Minimalism (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 13-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/OneTimeFIJ.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/OneTimeFIJ.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>OneTimeFIJ  (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 14-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/underground.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/underground.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Underground (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 15-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/PortfolioStartAlt.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/PortfolioStartAlt.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Debut de portfolio (pas terminé)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 16-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/StarPizza2.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/StarPizza2.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Star Pizza (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <h3 style="color: white; font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; font-size: 18px; margin-left: 25px;">Autres</h3>
        <div class="holder"><!--image 17-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/PianoPoster.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/AfficheColored.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Affiche Concert de Piano (pas terminé)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

        <div class="holder"><!--image 18-->
            <div class="thumb"> <a href="images/Fireguitar.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
            </div><!--end thumb-->
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Logo Fire Guitar (Projet de formation)</h3>
            </div><!--title end-->
        </div><!--holder end-->

    </div><!--gallery end-->
</div><!--wrapper end-->
<div id="footer">
    <p>Jonathan Levy|| Celtic Design Inc. © 2013.</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
    img {
    border: 0;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100#;
    position: relative;
}
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

.box {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
.box img {
    z-index: 1;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px; /* choose any height */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Hope you guys would be able to help because it's really driving me mad! Thanks in advance (and if I broke any rules or posted it wrong I'm sorry...first message ever on Stackoverlow :D).

Edit*: btw, I tried erasing the "position: fixed" attribute and replacing it with a overflow hidden, which works for the portfolio page, but makes the footer go up on my other pages and even completely disappear on my Homepage. :(

Edit* 2: More CSS just in case

```
/*Nav*/
.links {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 960px;
    height: 10px;
    }
.home {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    left: 125px;
    }
.portfolio {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 350px;
}
.about {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;
    left: 580px;
}   
.contact {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: 740px;
}
/*Nav End*/
```

Edit* 3: Ok, so I totally forgot to upload the CSS for the page of my portfolio (it has 3 CSS files [a lightbox.css/styles.css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css since it's the only page that uses a lightbox).

```
lightbox.css:
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#wrapper{
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
#wrapper #gallery {
    width:900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
#gallery .holder {
    width: 225px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:url(images/polaroid.png);
    float: left;
}
.holder .thumb {
    width: 140px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: 29px;
    margin-left: 43px;
}
.holder .title {
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title h3{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
}
.holder img {
    border: none;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
}
```

and jquery.lightbox-0.5.css:

```
#jquery-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 90;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
#jquery-lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
}
#jquery-lightbox a img { border: none; }
#lightbox-container-image-box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#lightbox-container-image { padding: 10px; }
#lightbox-loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
}
#lightbox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#lightbox-container-image-box > #lightbox-nav { left: 0; }
#lightbox-nav a { outline: none;}
#lightbox-nav-btnPrev, #lightbox-nav-btnNext {
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
    display: block;
}
#lightbox-nav-btnPrev { 
    left: 0; 
    float: left;
}
#lightbox-nav-btnNext { 
    right: 0; 
    float: right;
}
#lightbox-container-image-data-box {
    font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px 0;
}
#lightbox-container-image-data {
    padding: 0 10px; 
    color: #666; 
}
#lightbox-container-image-data #lightbox-image-details { 
    width: 70%; 
    float: left; 
    text-align: left; 
}   
#lightbox-image-details-caption { font-weight: bold; }
#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber {
    display: block; 
    clear: left; 
    padding-bottom: 1.0em;  
}           
#lightbox-secNav-btnClose {
    width: 66px; 
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 0.7em;  
}
```

SORRY FOR THE HORRIBLY LONG POST! ^_^

Comment: what's #body supposed to be used for? you don't have id="body" anywhere in your html?

Comment: You're right Daniel Morgan, I deleted it..I have no idea why I placed it there..still no changes though seeing as I had no #body attribute :P (I deleted #container as well..didn't had any attribute using it..)

Comment: on your footer, as well as having bottom:0; have you tried putting left:0; as well...?

Comment: Just did, still not working..doesn't really change anything

Comment: This isn't all of your CSS is it? Would you be able to put more of it on

Comment: Added the CSS for the nav, the rest of my css is for the other pages like contact and index page...where the footer stays put.

Answer (score 0):

try to use sticky footer

Follow the steps below:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: I would though I have no idea how to adapt it to my own code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be solve by setting some higher z-index value on ur footer id:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px; /* choose any height */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

**z-index:9999;**